# Can one say 'hi' to a person older than oneself?

Tags: politeness

Would it be appropriate to say 'Hi', for example, to a person at the ticket window who is seemingly much older than yourself?

Would it be a different case, say in Australia, where people usually refer to each other just by given names?

Comment: how would you know the given name of the person at the ticket window if they didn't have a name tag?

Comment: What country are you hypothetically in?

Comment: I don't want to know their name, I just gave an example of how easygoing people are there.

Comment: @user867 : Good point - if it's Mongolia, I think 'Hi' might not be appropriate.

Comment: I'm mostly interested in Australian case, but wouldn't mind an answer for other countries, either.

Comment: In Australia, unless you're talking to an actual foreign head of state, "Hi" is an acceptable greeting. Even at funerals. Unless it's the funeral of a foreign head of state, and even then it's still probably OK. So, unless you're buying tickets to the funeral of a foreign head of state, "Hi" is unlikely to offend an Australian ticket vendor.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about cultural expectations and not about English language and usage.

Comment: @user867, I would upvote that answer! lol!

Comment: @tchrist: I would have to dissagree with you. I'm more then convinced that language and culture are connected. I can give you examples in my first Russian language, or say Japanese. Yes, it is partially about cultural expectations, but it is about language, too.

Anyway, I found this question interesting to discuss, if you know a better place to ask it, please advise.

Comment: @tchrist: what do you mean by 'cultural error'?

Comment: @KristinaLopez Alas, my only reference for that is my own experience, and I've really only ever bought tickets in my home city. For all I know, they do things differently in Darwin.

Comment: @msgmaxim The cultural error is the mistaken assumption that the acceptability of saying “hi” to someone is somehow related to that person’s age.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m British, and am probably older than most people who greet me. I don’t mind when they say, as they very often do, ‘Hi’, but I don’t normally use it as a greeting myself.

Comment: It's more precise than 'Good Morning'. http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/14559-good-morning-said-bilbo-and-he-meant-it-the-sun

Comment: Perhaps, but 'Hi' is more versatile.

Answer (score 1):

In Denmark it is 'hi' everyone to everyone, for example. Not sure about Australia, though. To be on the safe side, I would use formal greetings until I've made sure it won't insult anyone if I switch to less formal one.

Comment: I am pretty sure there's no Danish English:)

Comment: I'd not be so sure :) Danglish, anyone? (http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Danglish). Besides, just go to Denmark and talk to people there—much more convincing than any dictionary article.

Comment: I know, I've lived in Denmark for some time, too :)

Comment: Funny, hadn't heard it before.

Comment: But it's not Danish English, it's just the way to say "Hello" in Danish language and it is spelled 'hej'

Comment: Perhaps they would greet me in Danish, then switch to Danish English, because I didn't speak Danish and I could understand what they were saying :)